# How can i send dynamic data in bootstrap file for Email in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am sending email to user while registration. For that i am using Zend's default function.
For that i added code in my Bootstrap file.

```
protected function _initMail()
    {
        try {
            $config = array(
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'username@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'ssl' => 'tls',
                'port' => 587
            );
            $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e){
        }
    }
```

Now my need is username,password and port i want to make this field dynamic. I want to fetch this record from the database. Can anyone please tell me how can i solve that problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you do not put these into the database. A better way would be to put them into a config file and then set them up from there. Doing a database call **EVERY SINGLE** time your application is called is not really optimal.

The way you should be doing it is:

```
protected function _initMail()
    {
        try {
            $config = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');

            $config = $config->getOption("mail");
            $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e){
        }
    }
```

That is assuming that your application.ini has this:

```
mail.auth="login"
mail.username="username@gmail.com"
mail.password="password"
mail.ssl="tls"
mail.port=587
```

*However* if you decide you want to do this, and have set up your database in the application.ini file (assuming you use ini files for config) something like this:

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "your.database.host"
resources.db.params.dbname = "database_name"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

You can then do:

```
protected function _initMail()
{
    $resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('db');
    $db = $resource->getDbAdapter();
    $select=$db->select()->from("emailSetup");
    $credentials=$db->fetchOne($select);
    [..email part here..]
}
```

P.S. I have not tested the select, but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got solution i made plugin for this.

Comment: @Nikul You'ŗe welcome! Feel free to set the answer as accepted if it was helpful.